# Is Machine Learning persona available for Databricks community edition?

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition, databricks-ml

I just started using [Databricks community edition](https://databricks.com/product/faq/community-edition), and by default I am in the "Data Science and Eingineering" persona. I wanted to explore the [Machine Learning](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/index.html) environment, but could not find such options from the sidebar (see below). Is the feature supported for community edition at the moment?

[image]

EDIT: it becomes available as of 9/10/2021.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now this functionality isn't available on community edition yet. You still have access to some pieces, like, MLflow, etc. but not UI for it. The ML persona UI is available in the full edition on all clouds (Azure, AWS, GCP).

Update 10.09.21: it’s available now :-)

Comment: It becomes available now :)

Comment: Yeah, changes are happening fast